# MongoDB Charts does not allow me to report on city, country although the values exist as the document also stores GeoJson

Tags: mongodb

I have a collection containing a location object defined with the following fields:

- city
- state
- country
- coordinates [Array]
  lat
  long

I want to report on cities / state / countries - not only on GeoJSON. Unfortunately, MongoDB Charts doesn't show city, state, country. it only presents me with the geo coordinates that I can only visualise on a map. This is of no value to me right now.

MongoDB Compass can see all fields, so do other 3rd party tools (such as knowi.com) but not MongoDB Charts! This is driving me nuts and I am finding it ridiculous to be in this situation.

Has anyone got an idea of what I should do to make it spit out my data in charts?

thank you!

I connected my MongoDB Atlas DB to third party tools such as Knowi.com, to MongoDB Compass, to Studio 3T which are all showing the fields.

Knowi.com is a data visualisation tool that actually is giving me the results I want for this but why using a 3rd party tool given the fact that MongoDB charts is pretty good?

I am stuck.